# mysqldump dies on the same row. Analyze is fine. Timeouts are long

Tags: innodb, mysqldump

I have an innodb table with about 70M rows. Recently a cron job to back it up with mysqldump started failing at the same row.

Mysqlcheck also fails.

Mysqlanalyze runs fine and prints OK.

`Alter table` also fails with an orphan temporary table starting with # which I need to nuke later.

Here is the configuration:

```
skip-external-locking
event_scheduler = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G
**wait_timeout = 3600**
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1
sync_binlog     = 1
bind-address            = 192.168.0.100
key_buffer_size         = 32M
max_allowed_packet      = 64M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
tmp_table_size          = 3G
max_heap_table_size     = 3G
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 500
```

Host is on ubuntu 16.04.1, MySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper.

Any insight is highly appreciated.